# Intuition behind occurence of non central chi squared distribution in conditional coordinates of a random walk

Tags: distributions, intuition, random-walk

#### Description of background

- Consider a 2d random walk with drift:

  $$X(t) = \sum_{k=1}^t X_k \\
  Y(t) = \sum_{k=1}^t Y_k$$

  where each $X_k$ and $Y_k$ are independently exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda = 0.5$.
- Let's define $Y^\star$ as $Y(t^\star)$, where $t^\star$ is the time when $X(t)$ passes some boundary line.

This looks as following

[image: display of random walks along with histogram]

The curve added to the histogram is the density of a non-central chi-squared distribution.

A motivation for this random walk is in the question: [Compound Poisson Distribution with sum of exponential random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/273902/)

#### Question

My question is whether there is an intuitive explanation for why $Y^\star$ is non-central chi-squared distributed (with 2 degrees of freedom and non-centrality parameter equal to the boundary value).

#### Code for plot

```
### prepare empty plot
plot(-10,-10, xlim = c(0,30), ylim = c(0,30), xlab = "x(t)", ylab = "y(t)", main = "random walks")

### prepare empty variable 
ystar = rep(0,n)

### compute random walks and add them to the plot
### also, compute ystar 
for (i in 1:n) {
  x = cumsum(rexp(m,0.5))
  y = cumsum(rexp(m,0.5))
  lines(x,y, col = rgb(0,0,0,0.01))
  hit = min(which(x>bound))
  ystar[i] = c(0,y)[hit]
}

lines(c(bound,bound),c(-100,100), col  = 2) ### add boundary line


### create histogram
hist(ystar, freq = F, breaks = seq(-0.5,max(ystar)+1.5,0.5), xlim = c(0,40), main = "histogram of y*", xlab = "y*")

### add a curve for the non-central chi-squared distribution
zs = seq(0,50,0.1)
lines(zs,dchisq(zs,0,bound))
```

Comment: I just found this on Google and have the opposite question :) I will think about it and hopefully come back to you. Also, it is sad and confusing that nobody answered this yet. Seems like a valid and important question to me and not that hard for a semi experienced pro.

Comment: @zonksoft Could you share what your opposite statement is precisely?

Comment: @zonksoft I remember the question a bit better now. One approach that I wanted to try was to see whether some [reflection principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process)) could be used to get an exact distribution for that random walk. I haven't tried that yet (it is a hurdle for me that's not easily solved and requires some extra coffee and a big piece of paper to visualise)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure yet but I think my question is: Are all commonly used distributions (exponential, Gaussian, Poisson, Chi Squared, Gamma,...) the limit of an intuitive random walk process that incorporates the nature of the distribution? My question is rooted in epistomology and physics (e.g. if I perceive something to have a Poisson distribution, is it always a random walk; vice versa, if something seems completely random to me, is it always one of a set of commonly used distributions).

Comment: @zonksoft Ah, that's a lot more general, but more specificly your question could be 'can the non-central chi-squared distribution be intuitively described by a random walk' which is opposite from my question 'can this random walk be intuitively described by a non-central chi-squared distribution'. (Still more general as different random walks could answer your question).

Comment: Relating to your question, the exponential distribution and the Gaussian distribution are distributions that minimize entropy and can be described by random walks. The chi-squared distribution and gamma distribution can be derived from it. For the Poisson distribution I do not directly see a relationship with a random walk.

Comment: The inverse question might be useful. I could think of other ways of random walks that generate a chi-squared distribution and possibly I can see it as analoguous to the random walk here.